# TemplateBinding Padding to Border doesn't work for my Button

Tags: .net, wpf

`TemplateBinding` the `Padding` property to a `Border` (`bdInner`) in the `ControlTemplate` for my `Button` is not working (it pads the `Left` and the `Right` only but not the `Top` and the `Bottom`).

I've tried `TemplateBinding` the `Padding` for that border to the `BorderThickness` of my template instead and that does work?!

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ECECEC" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White" x:Name="bdOuter">
                    <Border x:Name="bdInner" CornerRadius="2" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="0.05" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#EDEDED" Offset="0.5"  />
                                <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="0.95"  />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="1.0"  />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdOuter" Property="Background" Value="#178140" />
                        <Setter TargetName="bdInner" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#D1BBE3B6" Offset="0.05" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#EDBBE3B6" Offset="0.5"  />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#D1BBE3B6" Offset="0.95"  />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="1.0"  />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdOuter" Property="Background" Value="#178140" />
                        <Setter TargetName="bdInner" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#D1BBE3B6" Offset="0.05" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#EDBBE3B6" Offset="0.5"  />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#D1BBE3B6" Offset="0.95"  />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="1.0"  />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdOuter" Property="Background" Value="#178140" />
                        <Setter TargetName="bdInner" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#D176C76D" Offset="0.05" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#ED76C76D" Offset="0.5"  />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#D176C76D" Offset="0.95"  />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="1.0"  />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What makes it so and how can I help it?

Comment: Is perhaps something somewhere in your project/code setting the padding for the button(s) to something else (and thus overriding the style setting for the padding)? To rule out such a possibility, try creating a new empty WPF test project, create a single button in it and assign your button style to it (should be doable in little to no time). Does the padding work in the simple test project?

Comment: Why are you thinking, it's not working? This example works for me with no problem! Are you sure you mean padding and not margin!!!

Comment: It's definitely the padding. So it must be overriden somewhere else but what would make it so that it only overrides the Top and the Bottom padding and not the left and the right? Thanks for checking this out Hamed.